# Linking related topics IR

Tags: text-mining, information-retrieval, information-extraction, named-entity-extraction

How to link **terms**(keywords entities) which have some **relation** among them through text documents . Example is of **google** when you search for a person it shows **recommendations** of other **people related to that person** .

[image]

In this picture it figured out **spouse** , **presidential candidate** , and **equal designation**

I am using **frequency count** technique . The more two terms **occur** in same document the more chance of them to have some relation. But this also links unrelated terms like pagemarks , verbs and page refences in a text document .

How should I improve it and is there any other easy but reliable technique ?

Comment: Now days, this could be done using graph embedding of the knowledge base

Answer (score 1):

You should look a few techniques

1.) **Stop word filtering**: it is common in text mining two filter words which are typically not very important as they are two frequent. Like `the`, `a`, `is` and so on. There are predefined dictionaries.

2.) **TF/IDF**: TF/IDF re-weights words on how much they separate documents.

3.) **Named Entity Recognition**: For your task at hand it might be sufficient to just focus on the names. Named entity recognition can extract names from documents

4.) **Linear Dirichlet Allocation**: LDA finds concept in documents. A concept is a set of words which frequently appear together.